# Blocking ransom-ware like Cryptolocker

Tags: firewall, virus, spam-prevention

Here's the scenario. We've got around 15 - 25 physical machines, a few virtual ones, 3 or 4 file servers, mobile devices - the works in a single domain. A user reported that they'd been infected with CryptoLocker (ransom-ware) and as they're part of the domain, there's no reason to suspect that the ransom-ware hasn't locked the shared files on the network drives or shared drives of other machines.

I noticed that the infection method was via email (a very believable email with a PDF attachment) so obviously a decent spam filter will be a good starting point but what bothered me the most was we have backups running that'll still backup these crypto'd files if any machine gets infected. As it could be months before opening a crypto'd file has been locked (most ransom-ware only give you 48 - 72 hours to recover your data before deleting the private key) what sort of things can we put in place to stop this happening, besides a decent A/V and spam filter.

It worries me that a few of these might slip through the net and there's nothing we can do once the machine is infected.

Answer (score 3):

> As it could be months before opening a crypto'd file has been locked
>   (most ransom-ware only give you 48 - 72 hours to recover your data
>   before deleting the private key) what sort of things can we put in
>   place to stop this happening, besides a decent A/V and spam filter.

You are doing everything you can.  Sounds like user education should be added to the list.

> It worries me that a few of these might slip through the net and
>   there's nothing we can do once the machine is infected.

Regular **Offline** backups is the only way to combat malware like Cryptolocker.  Cryptolocker is only the beginning.

Comment: It still bothers me. I've got backups stretching back 3-5 months (average) so recovering the files before they're being crypto'd isn't a problem, just seems like we're (IT personnel) are in for a tough time. User education is in place but as we all know, these things occasionally still happen. Like I said, the email was convincing.

I have to say though, I take my hat off to the concept - not the application.

Comment: @ScottMcGready - There isn't really a good answer to be honest.  Spear phishing isn't new.  One solution might not allowing any attachments in the traditional sense.  Share Drive is a product provided citrix.  Its online storage with lots of configuration ( how many downloads is valid for, how long its valid, ect ).  I am not making a flat out recommendation clearly, just might be something to consider,

Answer (score 1):

At the previous company I worked for we used a GPO to block all programs and applications from using the TEMP directory which seemed to help a lot. Our firewall showed several attempts from Cyrpto to get into the system but all failed. We also took regular backups, daily, weekly, monthly and quarterly. Apart from these steps the only other option is user education.